# Sound on multi-seat system?

Tags: linux, audio, slackware, multiuser

I have set up a multi seat system, distribution of input devices and displays is working.

Now I want to assign Audio devices to the users.
Audio is supposed to be played over HDMI, so the displays play the sound.

Playing sound on the displays is not a problem and already working, but only for one user, who then steers **all** output.

Is there some way to assign, say, display 1 and 2 to user 1, 3 and 4 to user 2, 5 and 6 to user 3 and so on?

I have pavucontrol (pulseaudio) already installed.

How can I set up a Multi-Seat system with independent sound outputs via pulseaudio? The users have seperate Graphics cards playing the sound.

Comment: Are you using `loginctl`?

Comment: @StephenKitt No, as this is a systemd thing. slackware doesn't support it.

Comment: I have no personal experience with Slackware, but I will comment that this type of thing is significantly easier if you have physically distinct audio cards for each seat, and use per-user sessions for sound servers (if done that way, you can just figure out what seat the user is at on login, and when their sound server starts, have it configured such that it can only touch their sound card).

Comment: "Separate *graphics cards* playing the *sound*"? Did you mean separate *audio* cards?

Comment: Nope. There is audio over HDMI, so it's the graphics cards that play the sound here.